# TableView delays when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

My TableView delays for loading cell when user scrolls.
 I found similar questions, but people in those questions using images or downloads something, or have 100+ cells.
 In my case I have four different cell types in one tableview (is it problem?) and one of them have various count and delays before load new one.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        UITableViewCell *tvCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierUpper];

        if (!tvCell) tvCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifierUpper];

        tvCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        _collectionMainInfoView.$width = self.view.$width;
        _collectionMainInfoView.$height = self.view.$height*0.45;

        [tvCell.contentView addSubview:_collectionMainInfoView];
        [tvCell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [tvCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        return tvCell;
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        EventsCell *eventCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierEvent];
        [eventCell setEvent:[Event getNextEvent]];
        return eventCell;
    }

    if (indexPath.row == soldiers.count + 1) {

        InviteOtherCell *cellInvite = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierInvite];
        return cellInvite;
    }

    else {

        ProfilesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.curSoldier = _curSoldier;
        cell.delegate = self;
//        [cell configureCellWithSoldier:soldiers[indexPath.row - 1]];
        [cell setRightUtilityButtons:[self rightButtons] WithButtonWidth:120];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

The last ones ( after "else {") has delay before showing

```
#ProfilesCell.m

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    _cardView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
    _cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
    _cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
}
```

Comment: Show content of ProfilesCell cell. Is it simple view?

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko few IBOutelts, nothing special, added awakeFromNib method to question

Comment: Try to detect this problem by Profiler (Xcode tool). Also try step by step comment code in the ProfilesCell - maybe you will understand your problem

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko, after I commented full awakeFromNib method its still delays, will try to test with Profiler (never used it before)

Comment: Also important to note, if structure of cell is complex - many constraints, it can lead to not smooth scrolling

Answer (score 0):

this code looks litlle bit messy to me.

1) you've defined some view `_collectionMainInfoView` that will be added to every dequeued cell in first section, thus you're not only retaining that view, but also readding it to your table view cell everytime this delegate method is called. 
I would propose to just create own subclass of cell that already contains main info view.
After that, you'll be able to register this UITableViewCell's subclass for your table view, thus you will get rid of this code

```
if (!tvCell) tvCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifierUpper];
```

- don't hold `_collectionMainInfoView` in your VC. That smells. How this view will be reused when you'll have multiple cells in first section? You'll probably end up with "jumping view" that will be referenced in several cells.

2) We don't see your implementation of `ProfilesCell`, thus it's pretty hard to say what could go wrong. If possible, try to setup your cell's view hierarchy directly in it's init. If that's not possible. Don't generate buttons `[self rightButtons]` everytime this delegate method is called.
You're also not following Objective-C code guidelines. Try to get through them.

For example in here:

`[cell setRightUtilityButtons:[self rightButtons] WithButtonWidth:120];`

your method parameters should start with lowercase

`[cell setRightUtilityButtons:[self rightButtons] withButtonWidth:120];`

3) For better readability I'd use switch in your control flow instead of if statement

Comment: Thanks for advices, this code is really looks messy. But can something of it resolve my problem? I added ProfilesCell awakeFromNib method, its pretty simple.

Comment: a) you can register as many types of cell's as you want. remember, that tableview has its own optimizations for cell's allocations. if you don't get 60fps there may be various reasons for that -> your cells contains lot of subviews or you're doing time consuming stuff (like view allocations/setup, heavy data load at the time delegate method is called). Since I haven't seen what's underhood (like in case of `[cell setRightUtilityButtons:[self rightButtons] WithButtonWidth:120];`) I cannot tell more. You've shown us only one unimportant `awakeNib` method of your `ProfilesCell`

Comment: you can easily track which place "harms" the most by profiling your runtime. Or you can simply comment some calls, that may have heavy load. Then you can go step by step. I would ofc use time profiler to hunt that problem down

Comment: with profiler I found that dequeueReusableView takes a lot of time and if see deeper there are some CoreText functions. I used 3 labels with system font and different sizes in my cell's xib file. Also i found similar question, the author of which found solution in changing xib to programatically writing... so its kinda wrong to create cell with xib?

Comment: I prefer code over xibs, it's easier mantainable for me (e.g. I've got simple interface for autolayout, thus all view positioning is matter usually of 2-3 lines of code), but it's matter of taste I guess. There are developers who want to see how the view looks like and xibs are good at that. I suspect that setting shadow on cell's. layer is the weak point. Try to comment it and measure it once more time.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that your UITableView scroll not smooth is that you execute long async works in main thread when you load a Cell. Try to find out which piece of code that can execute long work in async? 
Try to comment your 2 lines (just for test). What do you do in those 2 `set` function?

```
cell.curSoldier = _curSoldier;
```

and

```
[eventCell setEvent:[Event getNextEvent]];
```

Answer (score 0):

When scrolling is not smooth, normally async work is performed when the cell is being displayed. Based on your code I would suspect 2 lines:

1.
    cell.delegate = self;
Not really sure what you want to do here. It may cause a loop in the reference?

2.
Sometimes the new optimalisation rules in the compiler have problems with commands within commands. Like in your statement:

```
[cell setRightUtilityButtons:[self rightButtons] WithButtonWidth:120];
```

You can try to break this up in 2 separate statements and a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your tableview code, but creating shadows can cause a performance hit, especially if you are creating a lot. I suggest using the[`shadowPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410771-shadowpath)property, it will speed up your code dramatically.